# Single clock cycle RISC-V processor really operates in single cycle?

Tags: cpu-architecture, riscv

When I work on Single Cycle Processor, I got confused about single cycle processor really operates every instruction in one cycle, for example PC comes first to instruction memory and instruction is read as  I know instruction memory work on rising edge of clock whole this operation already takes one clock cycle and if this instruction is load then we need a second cycle to read this from data memory and one extra third cycle for writing register file. Because every serial clocked component will need clock to send holding data, but I don't understand how to information (data) will forward along all this clocked component in single cycle?

Comment: The single cycle MIPS and RISC V are teaching tools.  I don't know of any real implementations, does anyone?  Even the very first MIPS was pipelined.

Comment: @ErikEidt so, in signle cycle assumption, is all component can be considered combinational circuit element? In reality every store element need to one clock cycle as I know.

Comment: Right, the store elements in single cycle are limited to the general registers $0-$31 and the program counter; and those are supposed to update on clock edge.  There's always a lot of detail missing on these designs, so we don't really get into the data memory, for example, as to whether there are busses/registers (i.e. store elements) for address and data.

Comment: as far as the decode and execute, as some google search results imply, yes you need a long enough clock cycle for all the combinational logic to settle.   but you still have the fetch and data cycle problem.   and it may be that that is fine that the execution for most instructions is one clock, all combinational based on an instruction that is ready.   read cycles would need to take more/many clocks but that is expected as well as stalls waiting for fetches or reads or write buffers, etc...

Comment: other than memory sure you can do everything in a single cycle.   if you pull memory into it, sure you could have some amount of sram that is also part of this single cycle, the thing would be massive and slow, but technically possible.